# Options for renewing passports of minors

Tags: usa, passport-renewals, minors

USA here, Bay Area (CA).  Trying to renew my kids' passports (they're both under 16).  Are there any options beyond the listed "passport acceptance facilities" on travel.gov, nearly all of which are either USPS facilities or county/city government centers?  Neither of which have *any* appointments available - even looking quite far afield, both in time and location.

From what I can tell, none of the "passport expediters" are of any help here (even if I don't mind the cost), as you have to go to the acceptance facility anyway.  Is my only option to wait until the week or so before the trip and hope to get an "emergency" appointment?  Does USPS allow walk-ups?

Comment: I looked on USPS sites and there are a few slots available in SF (but of course the bay area is huge) in three weeks. So I guess you could get up early or stay late to book appointments as soon as they are available. USPS allows your search for available appointments in any nearby locations on a given date.

Comment: I renewed at the NYC center nearly 3 years ago, and it was fairly painless.  This was of course before COVID, so your experience today is likely to be rather different from mine back then; in particular it seems that the backlog for regular applications could be causing increased demand for emergency appointments.  The emergency appointments are not at acceptance facilities, though, but rather at passport offices run by the Department of State.  If you choose that route, USPS is not involved.  San Francisco's is at 450 Golden Gate Avenue.

Comment: @xngtng That's interesting, I don't see any when I search there.  Even at various different times... and unfortunately I've had very bad experiences with their browser app.  Seems very hard to get it to work properly... sigh.

Comment: E.g. a few places have time slots on 13/14 of April https://imgur.com/a/CqMkILs

Comment: Interesting, that didn’t show up when I looked!  I wonder if it’s an issue with the app having bad settings internally… sigh. Anyways April 13 is too late here I think - trip is 6 weeks from then, and expedited is no faster than 5-7 weeks.

Comment: How far are you willing to go? Kenwood and Calistoga have appointments on March 22 and 23. I was only searching for places with photo services.

Comment: Yeah, I've found some really far out, and that might be the only option.  in this question I was mostly hoping to find there was some other way to do this, because *this* way seems silly to the point of absurd...  I'm probably going to go this route (found one an hour away) but it means taking the kids out of school, which the school is going to love, and is really irritating.  Sigh.

Comment: Just find a Post Office location in a quiet neighborhood and stand in line for a while. Sure, it's not fun, and no, it's not as convenient as having an appointment, but sometimes, life just isn't fun or convenient. Take the kids and make it a lesson in patience. Both for them and for you.